Is permanova indicated for one factor with two levels?
I have some permanova tests results. One of them evaluated lead (Pb) concentration between males and females, and the other between three other variables. When I searched about non parametric tests, I understood that mann Whitney's test is often used for comparisons between two independent groups.
When I compare the results of both tests, they are different (mann-whitney p>0,05; permanova p<0,05). So I'm having doubts about accepting the permanova results. Is it really indicated for this comparison between males and females?
